# Upload/download files securly, winforms c# and asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, winforms, http, file-transfer

From a winforms application, I need to upload & download files to an asp.net web server using http/https.

- only need to send/receive one file at a time
- cannot use ftp, must use http/https
- need progress bar
- upload & download must be username/password authenticated

Is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 5):

The [WebClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tt0f69eh%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) class should be able to do everything you need to do. Use either `UploadFileAsync` Or `UploadDataAsync` for the upload (and their counterparts for the download), normal HTTP authentication for the username and password (see the `Credentials` property) and the `UploadProgressChanged` event for tracking progress for your progress bar.

Comment: What would be preferable to receive and send the data on the server end: webservice, wcf, or asp.net form?

Comment: Out of those, ASP.NET would probably be the easiest to use with plain WebClient.